# Merge lines in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to write a script that restores a file, but preserving the changes that may be done after the backout file is created.

With more details: at some moment I create a backup of a file (file_orig). Do some changes to the original file as well(file_my_changes). After that, the original file can be changed again (file_additional_changes), but after the restore I want to have the backup file, plus the additional changes (file_orig + file_addtional_changes). In general backing out my changes only.

I am talking about grub.cfg file, so the expected possible changes will be adding or removing parts of a line.

Is it possible this to be done with a bash script?

I have 2 ideas:

1. Add some comments above the lines I am going to change, and then before the resotore if the line differ from the one from the backed out file, to read the comment, which will tell me what exactly to remove from the line;
2. If there is a way to display only the part of the line that differs from the file_orig and file_additional_changes, then to replace this line with the line from file_orig + the part that differs. But I am not sure if this is possible to be done at all.

Example"

line1: This is line1

line2: This is another line1

Is it possible to display only "another"?

Of course any other ideas are welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: As you are talking about grub.cfg, it would be best to tell us what you are actually trying to do?  You generally should not need to edit this file by hand as there are other files provided to allow you to implement changes so they occur every time an update is made.  This is a standard x/y problem where you have not told us what you really want.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for `git`...

Answer (score 0):

Unclear, but perhaps if you're using a bash script you could run a `diff` on the 2 edited file and the last one and save that output someplace that you want to keep it? That would mean you have a copy of the changes.

Or just use git like everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use POSIX commands [`patch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html) and 
[`diff`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html).

- Create the backup:

  ```
  cp operational-file operational-file.001
  ```
- Edit the operational file.
- Create a patch from the differences:

  ```
  diff -u operational-file.001 operational-file > operational-file.patch001
  ```
- Copy the operational file again.

  ```
  cp operational-file operational-file.002
  ```
- Edit the operational file again.
- Create a new patch

  ```
  diff -u operational-file.002 operational-file > operational-file.patch002
  ```

If you need to recover but skip the changes from `patch.001`, then:

```
cp operational-file.001 operational-file
patch -i patch.002
```

This would apply just the second set of changes to the original file, as log as there's no overlap.

Consider using a version control system to keep records of the file changes.  Consider using date/time stamps instead of version numbers on the file names.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I tried your proposal but I end up with operational-file with the original content, and patch.002 that compares lines, which do not exist in the operational-file, so the command fails. What I tried is to have the following content of the files: operational-file: a; first update: a b; second update: a b c; And after the recover I want to end up with content: a c;

Comment: And although this is something very interesting to me, and new (so thank you for sharing that), in the environment where the script shoudl work, I do not have patch command, so it wont help much, but to experiment and learn new things. Thanks once again for your help.